# Folder permissions when running Symfony in Docker environment

Tags: php, caching, docker, permissions, symfony

I am running a Docker containers on OSX. Containers consist of:

1. Symfony
2. Nginx
3. php-fpm
4. Redis

This is a pretty common setup to run Symfony apps.

I am running into some weird folder permission issues and I'm getting this error: 
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Fbrb.png)

My Symfony can create a folder

```
/var/www/var/chache
```

but then it can't write into it. 
Once cache folder created, folder permissions are set to this:

```
10344 drwxr-xr-x 1 1000 staff    68 Apr 15 00:33 cache
```

Owner of the folder is my local OSX user, which Docker is running under.
I've tried to change folder permissions or owner from Symfony's CLI in Docker and it has no effect. 
I tried to `chmod -R 777` under my local console, permissions are changed, but then Symfony creates folder inside cache folder and can't write into it again.

I've also tried to disable caching in app_dev.php:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true); 
// $kernel->loadClassCache();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
```

And in config.yml:

```
twig:
    cache:        false
```

Nothing had effect, so I'm lost here.

Any ideas how to solve an issue?

Comment: I feel think post is kinda related to my issue but doesn't really solve it: https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/581

Comment: Just ran same exact set of dockers inside Ubuntu virtual box - everything works fine, so I'm guessing it's somehow related to OSX-Docker permissions issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not shown you Dockerfile, because of that I can give you an example of container with PHP-FPM where this problem is fixed:

This row is fixing permission error: `usermod -u 1000 www-data`

```
FROM debian:jessie  
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl \
                       mcrypt \
    && apt-get install -y php5 \
                       php5-fpm \
                       php5-cli \
                       php-pear \
                       php5-common \
                       php5-igbinary \
                       php5-json \
                       php5-mysql \
                       php5-mysqlnd \
                       php5-gd \
                       php5-curl \
                       php5-dev \
                       php5-sqlite \
                       php5-memcached \
                       php5-memcache \
    && usermod -u 1000 www-data

EXPOSE 9000
```

Comment: It worked for me. Such an easy solution! Massive thanks for help.

Comment: Could you add an explanation please. So `usermod` is setting the ID of the `www-data` user to `1000`, is it? How is that helping to resolve the permission issue here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

check the official documentation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#book-installation-permissions).

I'm on ubuntu and to solve permissions problems I execute this commands:

```
$ sudo setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:`whoami`:rwx app/cache app/logs
$ sudo setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:`whoami`:rwx app/cache app/logs
```