# Symfony 5 getDoctrine->getRepository() Invalid argument supplied for foreach() Doctrine CachedReader.php

Tags: foreach, doctrine, symfony5

Friends, there was a problem that I cannot solve. Doing as per Symfony 5 documentation throws an exception: Invalid argument specified for foreach (). The stack trace points to vendor / doctrine / annotations / lib / Doctrine / Common / Annotations / CachedReader.php: 107. And essentially it doesn't let me access the repository in the controller. Resetting the entire Symfony cache helps for one request, then again the Exception is repeated. Tried accesses directory accesses with cache, did not help. I will be glad to the decision.

**Entity:**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=AuthorRepository::class)
 */
class Author
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    // ...
}
```

**Repository:**

```
class AuthorRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Author::class);
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
class AuthorController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/author/create", name="author-create")
     * Method ({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function actionCreate(Request $request, ValidatorInterface $validator): Response
    {
        // throw ErrorException !!!
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Author::class);
    }
  
    // ...
 }
```

[method show Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4npRO.png)

[Stack Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eukjD.png)

[where the exception is throw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLlQx.png)

Answer (score 1):

These were the access settings inside the container. This post helped me:
[Folder permissions when running Symfony in Docker environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36636596/folder-permissions-when-running-symfony-in-docker-environment)

**Dockerfile:**

```
&& usermod -u 1000 www-data
```